# Al-Masjid an-Nabawi tilted minaret?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, masjid, grave

I came across below image claiming that the minaret is tilted away from [the Green Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Dome) to avoid it falling on the Dome in case of some natural disaster.

(Original image is from [commons.wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Madeena_masjid_nabavi_12122008230.jpg))

[image]

Questions:

- Is it tilted, if yes, by design or by age (structure failing causing the tilt)?
- If by design, was the intention to avoid the collapse onto the Dome?

I have tried [the Wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Masjid_an-Nabawi), and searched the net, nothing is mentioned about it being tilted (might have used the wrongs search words, feel free to point me to related articles)

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. This might be possible even if the grave itself was walled long ago. And it has at least two walls.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Thank you, not disagreeing, yes, it is possible. But would like to find some factual reference that the tilt was by architectural design to protect the Green Dome.

Answer (score 1):

I've added two horizontal and vertical lines to the original image and as you may see the image it self was not taken in a 100% horizontal angle.

[image]

As for this minaret it is known as the principal minaret or the south-eastern minaret and was re-built or renewed the last time by [Qaitbay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qaitbay) at this occasion. The new basis was established starting from the underground water using basalt rocks.

I couldn't find any reports about it being tilt or planed to avoid falling down on the prophet's () tomb.

Comment: Although lines help to see that everything is tilted, I wouldn't go with these lines, as camera tricks can *bend* things (there must be a better photography terms).

Answer (score -4):

No, that is not possible as a tilted minaret would have fallen over due to structural failure. Secondly a tilt is not a tilt until it is visible with a naked eye. Thirdly if there were any tilt in the minaret this website ([the Madain Project](https://madainproject.com)) would have had some information about it.

They do have a page regarding the al-Baqi Gate which mentions the minaret ([al-Baqi minaret](https://madainproject.com/baqi_gate_(masjid_al_nabawi))) you're referring to as well, and no mention of any tilt. The Madain Project is most detailed regarding Masjid an-Nabawi.